# Как сделать правильно ввод данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать ввод, чтобы код работал.
Смысл таков:

Для каждого введённого числа проверить:

- если число меньше 10, то пропускаем это число;
- если число больше 100, то прекращаем считывать числа;
- в остальных случаях вывести это число обратно на консоль в отдельной строке.

```
while a == int(input()):
    if a < 10:
        continue
    elif 10 < a < 100:
        print(a)
        continue
    elif a > 100:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    a = int(input())
    if a < 10:
        continue
    elif a > 100:
        break

    print(a)
```

если выводить в 1 строку надо, то

```
    print(a, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Для Python 3.8 и старше:

```
while (a:= int(input()))<=100:
    if a >= 10:
        print(a)
```

Comment: настолько просто, что даже сложно для меня)